# Storing Ordered Child Documents/Values in CouchDB/JSON?

Tags: json, couchdb, html-lists

What is the best way to store ordered documents in CouchDB?

Say I have 100 articles and I want to order them by just visibly placing them in an order I like, or I have 10,000 images and I want them to appear in a specific order other than by date/category/etc.  Is this best stored at the parent ("page" or "album" level), or child (image/article) level?

Should it be more like this:

```
{
    _id: myPage;
    articles: [myArticle14, myArticle5, myArticle2, myArticle20...];
}
```

or this:

```
{
    _id: myArticle14;
    position: 1;
}
```

... where `articles: [myArticle14, myArticle5, myArticle2, myArticle20...];` are the `_id`'s of te actual Article documents.

What are the benefits/drawbacks of each, and which do you find is easier to use as the app grows?

Answer (score 1):

Use one document per article, assuming it contains non-trivial data. One big "container" document is not a good idea - you'd waste lots of revisions for each little update of any article data. It'd also make conflict resolution a trouble.

Answer (score 1):

**First solution.**

*Advantage:* You can't have two articles on one position.

*Disadvantage:* To get articles in order, you need to get all the articles from DB and then filter only ones you need, or you need to call as many queries as articles you want to display on the page.

**Second solution**

*Advantage:* You can get all documents for one page in one query. Just create view where key is made of *page* and *position* and use *startKey* and *endkey* parameters to get only articles you need.

*Disadvantage:* It is possible to make a mistake and have more articles with the same position.

I would choose second solution.